# Ember-CLI - Detect hash-change function in ember

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, ember-cli, hashchange

I'm relatively new to ember I've come across a scenario in which a class name should remove from the body tag while the window location changes and I figured out some code snippet to do so.

```
Ember.$(window).on('hashchange',function(){ 
      Ember.$('body').removeClass("someclass");
   });
```

And it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue by using [willTransition](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/) function in Ember-Cli.
Heres the code snippet to perform DOM manipulation while changing the route.

```
willTransition: function() {
  Ember.run.next(() => {
     Ember.$('body').removeClass("someclass");
  });
}
```